# Finding overlapping segments in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, data-analysis

I have two pandas DataFrames A and B, with columns `['start', 'end', 'value']` but not the same number of rows. I'd like to set the values for each row in A as follows:

```
A.iloc(i) = B['value'][B['start'] < A[i,'start'] & B['end'] > A[i,'end']]
```

There is a possibility of multiple rows of B satisfy this condition for each i, in that case max or sum of corresponding rows would be the result. In case if none satisfies the value of `A.iloc[i]` should not be updated or set to a default value of 0 (either way would be fine)

I'm interested to find the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: You want to set the value column for data frame A dependent on your boolean condition is that correct?

Comment: @EdChum Yes, but A and B don't have the same number of rows

Comment: Could you update your question with your new comment as it clarifies things more, also explain how you want to merge the rows in the situation where you have fewer rows in A or B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
lenB = 10
lenA = 20
B_start = np.random.rand(lenB)
B_end   = B_start + np.random.rand(lenB)
B_value = np.random.randint(100, 200, lenB)

A_start = np.random.rand(lenA)
A_end   = A_start + np.random.rand(lenA)

#if you use dataframe
#B_start = B["start"].values
#B_end = ...

mask = (A_start[:, None ] > B_start) & (A_end[:, None] < B_end)
r, c = np.where(mask)
result = pd.Series(B_value[c]).groupby(r).max()
print result
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution is elegant but has a huge memory footprint for large arrays.